# Использование middleware и статических файлов

Tags: node.js, express

Сайт со страницами: логин и чат. Авторизация с записями куки.
Если я ввожу правильный логин попадаю в чат и наоборот.
Если стираю кукис, то из чата я должен перенаправиться на старницу логина, но у меня не получается это сделать.
Если использую  `res.redirect("/")` выдает ошибку:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Может я не правильно использую отправленные статические файлы?
Является ли это правильной логикой работы?

app.js

```
    app.use(function (req,res,next) {
    if(req.cookies['username']=='Anton')
    {
        next();
    }
    else {
        if (req.body.text == 'Anton') {
            console.log("I open");
            res.cookie('username', req.body.text, {maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: 
    true, singned: true});
            next();
        } else {
            console.log("I get data");
            res.send("<h1>Сначало зарегистрируйся,а потом уже чат</h1>");
            //res.redirect("/"); //если использую это код то выдает ошибку Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        }
    }
    });

    app.post("/chat",function (req,res,next) {
    res.redirect("/chat");
   //next();
    });
    app.use("/chat",express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

login.html

```
<form class="login-form" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/chat">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="text"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
            <button type="submit" >login</button>
            <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Уберите res.send и почитайте про http заголовки